# fix xslt bug for validation

Tags: xml, validation, xslt

I need to validate the value of Invoice element in XSLT: missing element = default to 1 (working)...blank = default to 1(working)...but 2 or any numbers in string which are not working because it keeps return to 1.

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction" >
  <Transaction invoice="{Invoice}">
    <xsl:attribute name="invoice">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Invoice and (@Invoice!='') and (@Invoice!='0')">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Invoice"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope to get any help from you. Would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Is Invoice an attribute or an node in your input xml? Seems, that you are always running in your default branch. `invoice="{Invoice}`this is using Invoice as node, but `@Invoice` is looking for Invoice as attribute.

Comment: Your question isn't clear but we would probably be able to answer it if you showed us an example of a Transaction element in your source document.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In the `when` condition use AND instead of and</strike> (seems only lowercase is good)

Start from a simple condition and add one at a time to see which one is bad:

```
<xsl:when test="@Invoice">
```

then

```
<xsl:when test="@Invoice and (@Invoice!='')">
```

then

```
<xsl:when test="@Invoice and (@Invoice!='') and (@Invoice!=0)">
```

althoug I would have wrote

```
<xsl:when test="@Invoice and (@Invoice &gt; 0)">
```

Comment: Last line it cannot be greater than 0 because it is a string.

Comment: Sorry, from your question it seemed they are numbers ("`...but 2 or any numbers which are not working because it keeps return to 1`")

Comment: Sorry i should have said numbers in string :) I am gonna edit my post thanks